# created JLabel in other class and implemented to main class not appears

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to make my code more clear and move labels from login screen to other class. when I implement JLabel in main class it's working fine, but when moving that outside it not appearing.

```
public LoginPanel ()  {

    frame = new JFrame ("Login");                               // initial frame, add title
    frame.setSize(500, 500);                                    // frame size
    frame.setLocation(300, 200);                                // set where program window should start
    frame.setLayout(null);                                      // set layout; you can use (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.LEFT));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       // closing the program by clicking X
    /*
    userLabel = new JLabel("enter user name label");            // create Label next to the user field
    userLabel.setLocation(10, 10);                              // set location where label will start to appear
    userLabel.setSize (userLabel.getPreferredSize());           //
    frame.add(userLabel);                                       // add userLabel to the frame
    */
    CredentialsFields fields = new CredentialsFields();
    frame.add(fields);
```

NEW CLASS TO WHERE I WANT TO MOVE JLABEL

```
public class CredentialsFields extends JComponent{

    JLabel userLabel;   

    public CredentialsFields() {

        super();
        userLabel = new JLabel("enter user name label");            // create Label next to the user field
        this.setSize (500,300); 
        this.setLocation(10, 10);
```

Comment: I highly recommend taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```java
public class CredentialsFields extends JPanel {

    JLabel userLabel;   

    public CredentialsFields() {

        super();
        userLabel = new JLabel("enter user name label");            // create Label next to the user field
        this.setSize (500,300); 
        this.setLocation(10, 10); 
        add(userLabel); // add the label to the current panel
}
```

1. For composite components it's better to inherit from `JPanel`
2. You didn't add your label to the container `CredentialsFields`